# Styling a custom spreadsheet menu item using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a custom menu on a Google Sheets:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var csvMenuEntries = [{name: "Save as CSV file", functionName: "saveAsCSV"}];
  ss.addMenu("Save New Emails", csvMenuEntries);    
}
```

I would like to style the menus I create.

Is this possible and how would one go about it?

All I really want to do is have a custom colour or background for the button to make it stand out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is supported by the current API.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't supported, but you can add some Unicode symbols to the menu entries' names so they stand out a little from the other options.

Most symbols from this site work:
http://copypastecharacter.com/

This is what I've been using to highlight some help menu entries.