# Using methods for the menu item callbacks in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, design-patterns, mvvm

So, I am doing a small project in Google Apps Script, to make adding/exporting leads from it...less painful.

### How do I plan to do this?

I plan on doing this via adding some `Actions` menu, for the importing and exporting of leads. The imported sheet will, for now, be assumed to be of the same columns as the Google Sheet this script is bound to. (We can support some sheet column conversion features later, but it's probably a YAGNI for my use case.) The exported sheet will be converted from the columns of this sheet, to some simplified, ready-to-send-to-the-mailers columns.

### How do I plan to code this (or how am I coding this)?

I am using MVVM design pattern, and have spent last night plugging away at writing MVVM wrappers for everything that I need to (keeping KISS in mind).

The `MenuItemViewModel`s have some `name`,`functionName` that the [Google Apps Script seem to be looking for](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/menu#additemcaption,-functionname). I note that there is some major pain-in-the-ass limitation, though: **Google Apps Script wants function NAME** and **it cannot be method**!

### OK, show me some code or gtfo

I have some `SpreadsheetPageViewModel` that look like this:

```
class SpreadsheetPageViewModel extends BaseViewModel {
  init() { 

    
    this.exportVM = new ExportSpreadsheetEditViewModel();
    this.importVM = new ImportSpreadsheetEditViewModel();

    this.menuVM = new MenuViewModel(new MenuModel(),
      [
        'exportLeads', // this is utility function. I want/need to use openExport method
        'importLeads', // this is utility function. I want/need to use openImport method
      ]);


    this.childEditVM = null;
  } 

  openExport() { 
    this.childEditVM = this.exportVM;
    this.childEditVM.view.doShow();
  }

  openImport() { 
    this.childEditVM = this.importVM;
    this.childEditVM.view.doShow();
  }
}
```

The business logic for the modals that spawn on menu item click, will live in the child view models to this: the `ExportSpreadsheetEditViewModel` and `ImportSpreadsheetEditViewModel`.

I was trying to get around the limitation via this hack:

changing

```
function onOpen(event) { 
  // show the menu here....
  new SpreadsheetPageView().doShow();
}
```

to something like:

```
var mainView;

function onOpen(event) { 
  mainView = new SpreadsheetPageView();
  // show the menu here....
  mainView.doShow();
}
```

and then, in the `MenuActionUtils.gs`, crawling down that `mainView` like:

```
function exportLeads() { 
  mainView.viewModel.showExport();
}

function importLeads() { 
  mainView.viewModel.showImport();
}
```

### What was the result of that hack?

It didn't work. Why? Because when Google Apps Script fired that `exportLeads` (or `importLeads`), `mainView` was no longer defined!!

Does this mean I have to give up my approach?
How can I use the main view/view model in the onClick of the menu items?
Failing all that, is there a way to create our menu, using this MVVM design pattern (and some HTML/React/....), and inject it in?

Comment: People downvote and vote to close this?!

What about this question makes them want to do that?!

Comment: This deserves some space here in SO. This post originally sums up the problem, so much so that it elucidates the nature of how things might work and not work when developing in the google script app ecosystem, and in particular points out something none of the developer doc over at Google covers at all: and what's happening is a subtle and important detail when developing in this space you should know before deploying live... My resolution involved converting to functionalism so that a mapping function reduced the array's returned from google sheet cells into a pipeline and out again to the ui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @Ruben's help, I was able to get this working!

### What I did

I didn't give up on the MVVM/OOP design.

Instead, I created singleton static method on the drive class, like so:

```
static GetMainInstance() { 
    if (!this._mainInstance) { 
      this._mainInstance = new this();
    }

    return this._mainInstance;
  }
```

and use it instead of directly creating the new drive object.

Also, it is view's responsibility to spawn stuff, so I did some refactoring:

In `PageView.gs` I added the following methods:

```
showExport() { 
    this.viewModel.showExport((childVM) => {
      this.editView.viewModel = childVM;
      this.editView.doShow();
    })
  }

  showImport() { 
    this.viewModel.showImport((childVM) => {
      this.editView.viewModel = childVM;
      this.editView.doShow();
    })
  }
```

in the `PageViewModel.gs`, I changed the methods to accept `onDone` callback:

```
showExport(onDone) { 
    this.childEditVM = this.exportVM;
    onDone(this.childEditVM);
  }

  showImport(onDone) { 
    this.childEditVM = this.importVM;
    onDone(this.childEditVM);
  }
```

Simple fix, it works, while staying consistent with the principles!

Comment: Thank you. After not coding many years later I came to work in a warehouse whose software was based on google sheets, and knowing what I know finding out about google scripts gave me an idea to make a ui, probably not unlike the data you might handle. A few rewrites and two weeks later, I finished almost everything I could handling TDD with emulation, so that only clasping it in, and it should be good to go as far as I could control it. Everything worked, but with the inconsistency of the model regenerating! For the same reason you came to find. Could you elaborate what your drive class means?

Answer (score 1):

By using Google Apps Script it's not possible to modify the look and feel of a Google Workspace editor (Docs, Forms, Sheets, Slides) custom menu, in other words, it's not possible to use HTML/React for this but you might use them in dialogs/sidebars.

Regarding using a design pattern, you might use any design pattern that you want but you should have in mind that every time that a Google Apps Script is triggered by an event the whole project is loaded, so if you need that some objects persist between events then you should find a place to save those objects.

To store an object you might use the Google Apps Script Properties Service and/or the Cache Service, just bear in mind that you should convert it to JSON before saving it. Also you might use a Google spreadsheet but this has several limitations or you might use an external service, i.e. nosql database, by using Google Apps Script URL Fetch service.

Related

- [using and modifying global variables within handler functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12549085/1595451)
- [Styling a custom spreadsheet menu item using Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14533122/1595451)
- [How to define global variable in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24721226/1595451)
- [Google Apps Script (V8); why can't I use an object instance inside of onOpen?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60218503/1595451)

Comment: Thank you for the input!

With a little extra thinking about the design, I was able to get it working!!